# Can I run Python server in Terminal and commit to Github while it's running?

Tags: python, git

I like to start Python server in the Terminal, so that I can preview page that I'm working on:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If I try to add, commit files to Github through Terminal, I have to quit Python server, commit, and then restart Python again.

Is there an easier way to do it, so that Python server is running, and I can commit to Github at the same time?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Opening a second Terminal window?

Comment: Adding & at the end worked. Thanks @matsjoyce

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about opening a 2nd terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running in the same terminal, you can run the process in the "background" by "forking" it. In `bash`, you fork a process by adding a ampersand (`&`) to the end of the command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

This will allow you to run your other processes simultaneously. `bash` will print the process id for the forked process:

```
$ sleep 100&
[2] 27208
```

This will allow you to later kill the process:

```
$ kill 27208
```